# NSThread issue with an iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

I have a rather complex application at https://github.com/BigBadOwl/iStreamer-Download-Manager which uses Rtmpdump and Ffmpeg libraries to download and convert Flash streams. I would like the thread which does the actual conversion to be released to give the user access to the screen again during the download (for obvious reasons).

Anyway, it runs fine as long as it's in the main thread, but as soon as I try place it on a new thread, the Rtmpdump code crashes. It's a memory thing, but I can't see where I am going wrong. Does anyone mind telling me whats going on?

The part of the code in question is https://github.com/BigBadOwl/iStreamer-Download-Manager/blob/master/iplayerFetch.m

```
- (void)startTheBackgroundJob:(NSArray *) args {
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

 NSString *thePid = [args objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *flvPath = [args objectAtIndex:1];
 NSString *mp4Path = [args objectAtIndex:2];
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressBar:) withObject:flvPath waitUntilDone:NO]; 
 [self getFlashFile:thePid withFlvPathName: flvPath];

 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:flvPath]){
  NSNumber *filesize = 0;
  NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]     fileAttributesAtPath:flvPath traverseLink:NO];
  if(fileAttributes != nil){
   filesize = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
  }

  if([filesize longLongValue] > 1024){
   [self removeFlvWrapper:flvPath withMp4PathName:mp4Path];
  }
  [fileManager removeItemAtPath:flvPath error:NULL];
 }

 [fileManager release];
 [pool drain];}

    - (void)beginDownload:(NSString *) thePid withDocumentsFolder:(NSString *)         documentsDirectory andTempFolder:(NSString *) tempDirectory {
     NSString *flvPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.flv", tempDirectory, thePid];
     NSString *mp4Path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp4", documentsDirectory, thePid];

     NSArray *extraArgs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:thePid, flvPath, mp4Path, nil];
     [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startTheBackgroundJob:) toTarget:self withObject:extraArgs];}
```

Stacktrace:

```
#0  getStream (argc=16, argv=0x65a0140) at /Users/colinb/Documents/iStreamer-Download-Manager/rtmpdump.c:746
#1  0x0003c297 in -[iplayerFetch getFlashFile:withFlvPathName:] (self=0x658ced0, _cmd=0x58da66, thePid=0x793e8b0, flvPath=0x65994c0) at /Users/colinb/Documents/iStreamer-Download-Manager/iplayerFetch.m:168
#2  0x0003b776 in -[iplayerFetch startTheBackgroundJob:] (self=0x658ced0, _cmd=0x58daca, args=0x6599490) at /Users/bigbadowl/Documents/iStreamer-Download-Manager/iplayerFetch.m:33
#3  0x019a4d4c in -[NSThread main] ()
#4  0x019a4cd8 in __NSThread__main__ ()
#5  0x97ca385d in _pthread_start ()
#6  0x97ca36e2 in thread_start ()
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

[image]

Comment: Really need a stack trace to figure out what is wrong... probably main thread and the thread you have in the background (if that is the thread that crashed).

Comment: Currently the console only shows me this 2010-12-03 21:10:50.817 DownloadManager[6828:307] progress is:0.000000
2010-12-03 21:10:50.826 DownloadManager[6828:307] filesize is:0
2010-12-03 21:10:51.828 DownloadManager[6828:307] progress is:0.010000
2010-12-03 21:10:51.833 DownloadManager[6828:307] filesize is:0
2010-12-03 21:10:52.836 DownloadManager[6828:307] progress is:0.020000
2010-12-03 21:10:52.841 DownloadManager[6828:307] filesize is:0
[Switching to thread 14339]
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
[Switching to thread 14339]

Comment: Just curious, but why update the "progress bar" UI from inside the thread with an argument you passed into the thread? That argument is available outside of that processing thread, so why not update that UI before the thread spawns?

Comment: To be honest, I've not completed that part of the code yet, it's just a brain dump at the moment - I'm trying to get the threading running, then get the Progress updater going.

Comment: Updated with an image of the debugger output, I have also added NSZombieEnabled but I don't see any show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## When a crash occurs, there will be a backtrace.

Post it.

Either your program will break in the debugger, and the call stack will be in the debugger UI (or you can type 'bt

With that, the cause of the crash is often quite obvious.  Without that, we are left to critique the code.

---

The memory management between threads is very haphazard in the code posted.   `extraArgs` is being leaked, most likely.   You need to `release` it in the receiving thread (or in the main thread once you know the receiving thread is done with it).  Note that `autorelease` cannot be used to transfer ownership of an object from one thread to another.

Given the lack of a crash and the claim that the code works fine on main thread, but not when threaded, my best guess is that you are abusing a non-threadsafe API from multiple threads, potentially also triggering UI updates from outside the main thread.

Namely, is `removeFlvWrapper:*` thread safe?   Remember that the Foundation collection classes are *not thread safe*.

---

Is your `[self getFlashFile:thePid withFlvPathName: flvPath];` method thread safe?  What about the function it calls?   Is this being fired up only once or do you have multiple threads?

Comment: Thanks just double checking everying, removeFlvWrapper is a method in the my code.

Comment: getFlash File is my method that calls getStream(rt_argc, rt_argv) in my code. getStream was the main() method of the original rtmpdump code.

Answer (score 0):

It's often best to use a process of elimination to find these types of bugs.

When running in the main thread, `-updateProgressBar:` won't run until the download has completed.  You should remove it until you've isolated the problem.

Also, `NSFileManager` instances are not thread safe, so you cannot use `[NSFileManger defaultManager]` from your background thread.  Instead, you must create a new instance of NSFileManager to be used from your background thread.  e.g., `[[NSFileManager alloc] init];`

You should also try to capture the crash while stepping through the code.  This may give a better idea of where the problem is.  The line number reported in the callstack (rtmpdump.c:746) doesn't make much sense.  You should try to get a better idea of where the crash is occurring.  Does it occur on the same line every time, or does it vary?  And which lines?

Also, why are these declared static?

```
static char **rt_argv;
static int    rt_argc;
```

Declaring them static here makes them global variables, which will absolutely cause fatal problems when you try to run multiple download threads.

Comment: Thanks Darren, I've made those changes. I've also double checked the stack using gdb. [Switching to process 1677]
[Switching to process 1677]
(gdb) continue
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
[Switching to process 1677]
[Switching to process 1677]
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
(gdb) up
#1  0x0003e926 in getStream (argc=16, argv=0x7853ce0) at /Users/user/Documents/iStreamer-Download-Manager/rtmpdump.c:746
746   RTMP rtmp = { 0 }; //crash around about here
Current language:  auto; currently c